# Case insensitive matching and replacing while respecting casing of source string

Tags: javascript, replace, case-insensitive

I want to make the case insensitive matching part of value of `query` within value of `s` bold.

If I find `query` within `s` I **can't** simply do:

```
var s="New York";    
var query="new";

var result = s.replace(/query/i,'<strong>' + query + '</strong>';
```

Since then it will also replace the casing in `s` with the casing in `query`, which I don't want. I want to keep the casing as in s.

Result would have to be: "**New** York"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you make it a capture group (by surrounding it with parentheses), then you can use the placeholder `$1`:

```
var s="New York";  
var result = s.replace(/(new)/i,'<strong>$1</strong>');
// result = <strong>New</strong> York
```

see live example: http://jsfiddle.net/2zau4/

---

As pointed out in comments - and something which I never knew about - is that you dont actually need the capture group as javascript uses characters `$&` to represent "the entire match". So you could also do this:

```
var s="New York";  
var result = s.replace(/new/i,'<strong>$&</strong>');
// result = <strong>New</strong> York
```

---

As a final note I assume you realise that you original syntax will not work:

```
var s="New York";    
var query="new";

var result = s.replace(/query/i,'<strong>' + query + '</strong>';
-----------------------^
This is searching for literal "query" not 
  the variable query (containing the string "new")
```

The correct syntax must create a `RegExp` from a string with the "i" flag:

```
var s="New York";    
var query="new";

var result = s.replace(new RegExp(query,'i'),'<strong>$&</strong>');
```

Comment: No need for the group, just use `$&`.

Comment: @Jamiec If the criteria for the regex is stored in a var, will the OP need to use `new RegExp()`?

Comment: Id say yes, but I assumed the OP knew that part. Maybe I should update these to use that syntax to make it clear.

Comment: @Jamiec: thanks! :) I can't edit it myself because it's too short an dit but the last statement in you answer needs a parenthesis before the last semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

```
var s="New York";    
var query="new";
var result = s.replace(new RegExp(query,"i"),function(match){
   return "<strong>" + match + "</strong>";
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/F7Y8y/2/